# Output voltage doubling on power supply, possible culprits?

Tags: power-supply

I've had to repair a few of these power supplies that are from moving head effect lights. They've all needed to be recapped and a couple have had bad variable pots, but this one is getting an output voltage double of what it should be (after doing the aforementioned repairs). It's 120VAC in, should be 12VDC/28VDC output (I'm reading closer to 24/48 output). I've tested quite a few components and can't really track down the potential culprit. The large resistors near the DC connections are getting hot quickly, I've pulled and tested one of them and they're within spec.

[image]

Comment: They may not regulate correctly at no-load. Are you testing open circuit?

Comment: You may have pulled a plate-thru when you replaced the capacitors.

Comment: I'm certainly not testing it at full load, but I'm running a small fan on it when I typically set the variable pot, and that seems to remain consistent when I test it with full load. I've done quite a few of these in a similar way, this is the first one I've seen doubled voltage